# Run Discord.py as an asyncio subprocess

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am trying to run the Discord python bot in the background of my main script. I was thinking that subprocess would probably the best way to archive that. But I can't figure out any way to run the Discord bot as a subprocess. I would also like to start and stop the Discord bot via a function.

My Discord bot script looks like this:

```
import time
import asyncio
import discord

TOKEN=('----')
    
client=discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!test'):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Test", color=0x0071ce, description="Test")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
client.start(TOKEN)
```

**EDIT:**

I am calling this script from my main script which is a menu. I can't post the main script here because it's to long but it looks like this:

```
from menu import Menu
import subprocess
from os import system, name 

def clear(): 
    if name == 'nt': 
        _ = system('cls') 
    else: 
        _ = system('clear') 

class discord():
    def start(self):
        clear()
        subprocess.run("discord_script.py")
    def stop(self):
        clear()
        #here I would like to stop the subprocess

class MainMenu():
    def __init__(self):
        mainpage_options = [
            ("Start discord", discord().start),
            ("Stop discord", discord().stop),
            ("Close and save", Menu.CLOSE)
        ]
        self.mainpage = Menu(
            options=mainpage_options,
            title="Main Menu",
            message="This is the Main Menu. \nPlease seelect something."
            )
        self.mainpage.set_prompt(">")

    def open(self):
        self.mainpage.open()
MainMenu().open()
```

The problem is that `subprocess.run("discord_script.py")` won't start the subprocess and also I don't know how to stop it if its running. Maybe the subprocess module is not the right thing to use.
The error I'm getting is:

```
File "discord_script.py", line 9
    async def on_message(message):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is strange because if I'm running the script the normal way it's working fine.

Comment: Is your main script already using asyncio?

Comment: No my main script is not using asyncio at all. My main script is basically a menu.

Comment: Then you can just use the `subprocess` module.

Comment: yes I thought that, but my problem is I can't figure out how to use the subprocess module.

Comment: `subprocess.run(“/path/to/script”)`

Comment: @dirn I really can't get the script to work with `subprocess.run`. No matter what I try.

Comment: Perhaps you can share what you've tried. So far all we can see if the code that appears to be the script you're trying to run, but without seeing how you're trying to run it, all we can do is guess.

Comment: @dirn I edited my post so hopefully its now a little clearer what I am doing.

Comment: Why can't it run `discord_script.py`? Can it not find the find? Is there a problem running the script? Do you need to pass the environment? Please also include error information.

Comment: @dirn Sorry, thought I added it. Now I edited the post again.

Comment: That means you're running `discord_script.py` with a version of Python prior to 3.5. You can fix that by adding a shebang to your script that points to a more recent version or calling a more version version of Python with `subprocess.run` and passing the name of your script as an argument. You can probably also fix it by making the `python` executable refer to a more recent version as well.